# Sesame API call throwing an IOException

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans, sesame

I am writing a program in Java to consume the services of Sesame but when I call Login:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {        
     try {

    URL sesameurl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame");
    SesameService service = Sesame.getService(sesameurl);         
        service.login("username", "password");
        service.getRepositoryList();            
               } 
    catch (UnknownRepositoryException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sparqlquery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sparqlquery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        catch (AccessDeniedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sparqlquery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }      
    PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();         
}
```

it throws the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
```

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.io.IOException: http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/servlets/login: Not Found

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1

Comment: Show the relevant code please.

Comment: With 'relevant code' I mean the part where you create and initialize the Sesame Repository object. Also: can you show the full stacktrace of the exception? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28083009/edit) to add these details.

Comment: By the way, as you're relatively new here: I have noticed you have asked several questions, but have never upvoted and/or accepted any of the answers you were given. Of course it's not _required_, but it's a good way to thank someone if their answer has been helpful to you. Have a look at this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have added the code and the error as shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you got this code example from, but the classes `SesameService`, `Sparqlquery`, or `UnknownRepositoryException` do not exist in Sesame 2.

You are either using a *very* old version of Sesame (1.x, which is no longer supported and has not been since at least 2007), or you are using some third-party wrapper library.

Make sure you are using a recent version of Sesame (latest stable release can be found on the [website](http://rdf4j.org/)).

The correct/current way to connect to a Sesame Server is as follows:

```
 // connect to the server
 String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame";
 RepositoryManager manager = RepositoryProvider.getRepositoryManager(serverUrl);

 // get a list of the ids of all existing repositories
 List<String> ids = manager.getRepositoryIDs();

 // open a repository with a known identifier, e.g. "test"
 Repository rep = manager.getRepository("test");
```

And so on. For further details on how to work with Sesame, see the documentation available on the [Sesame website](http://rdf4j.org/), in particular the [tutorial](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/tutorials/getting-started.docbook?view), the chapter ["Programming with Sesame"](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#Programming_with_Sesame), and the [API Javadoc](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/).